# number of days needed : 48-hour project with 4 employees working 6 hrs/day?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The paving of a road takes 48 hours if done by an employee. As a Project Manager, calculate the number of days required if you have a workforce of 4 people who can work for 6 hours a day?

Comment: The task needs $48$ man hour. You can employ $4\cdot6=24$ man hour per day

Comment: @amWhy, person-hour is probably a more commonly used term:)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes indeed. Just teasing, any way ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$4\;\text{persons}\times \frac{6\;\text{hours}}{\text{day}} \times x\;\text{days} = 48 \;\text{person-hours}$$

$$\text{Solve for x}: \quad 24x = 48 \iff x = \dfrac {48}{24} = 2\;\text{days}$$

Comment: 4 people x 6 hours == 24
  , 48 hours / 24 == 2
 
......Thank you ^_^

Comment: @amWhy: Needs a TU! +1